# ASP.NET MVC Data Insertion in Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, insert, sql-insert

How to insert only limited records in Table?
I want insert just 10 record in my SQL server table.

Comment: Your question isn't clearly. Please attach your code or improve the question

Comment: If you are using SQL directly, then you want the [**TOP** clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you are using Entity Framework or some other ORM, then you probably want the [**Take** LINQ method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.take?view=net-5.0). But you really need to clarify your question some more.